# in ruby, how can I serialize an array and preserve the numeric/string type of each element?

Tags: ruby, serialization

My app imports some csv data, and I build an array, serialize it, and save it in a database field.  I save it in serialize form because the data imported each time has a different structure ... sometimes 3 columns, sometimes 10 columns, etc.

[["fruit", "price", "weight"],
["Apple", 1.23, 4.5],
["Orange", 5.2, 3.3]]

The imported data has quotes around strings, and no quotes around numbers, so during the import I am able to preserve the type of each element.

But when I serialize it (to save in a database field) with `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(csv_data)`
each element gets saved as a string

[["fruit", "price", "weight"],
["Apple", "1.23", "4.5"],
["Orange", "5.2", "3.3"]]

so when I de-serialize it, the numeric values have been converted to strings, but I need them as numeric for the post-processing.

The problem is, each data import is different... sometimes it;s all numeric, sometimes the first column is string, sometimes 2 or 3 columns might be strings.

I don;t care if i use JSON or not -- I just need a way to encode and decode the data so I can stuff it into a database field, without losing the 'type' durign the decode.

Should I be using some sort of xml method instead of JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html) to the rescue!

```
tmp = [["fruit", "price", "weight"], ["Apple", 1.23, 4.5], ["Orange", 5.2, 3.3]]
dmp = Marshal.dump(tmp)
p Marshal.load(dmp)
# => [["fruit", "price", "weight"], ["Apple", 1.23, 4.5], ["Orange", 5.2, 3.3]]
```

Comment: Note that the Marshall format is incompatible between different versions (1.9 versus 2.0) and implimentations (MRI versus JRuby) of Ruby.